# MYSql multiple replace query

Tags: mysql, replace

I have this

```
UPDATE  table 
SET  example = REPLACE(example, '1', 'test') 
WHERE example REGEXP '1$'
```

So this code replaces all instances of "1" in the "example" field with "test".

I want to repeat this for 2, 3, 4 and so on.

But it would be very inefficient to use separate querys.

Is the any way I can do this with just one query?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to move it to a stored procedure, using a variable.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Matryoshka-way ;-)

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(example, '3', 'test') , '2', 'test') , '1', 'test')
```

Comment: Hi It worked. But what about the where clause. Even though it is not necessary. I read it's important to prevent errors.

Comment: what if I need to do this for 10 different strings? We should be using a procedure to make that more elegant I assume.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure.

Given you have a table 'lut' with a set of values that you want replacing in a field 'content' from a table is called 'example'

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE myreplace()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE lv CHAR(64);
DECLARE li INT;
DECLARE lut CURSOR FOR SELECT id,value FROM lut l;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN lut;
lut_loop: LOOP
FETCH lut INTO li,lv;
IF done THEN
LEAVE lut_loop;
END IF;
update example set content = replace(content,lv,li);
END LOOP; 
CLOSE lut;
END;
//
delimiter ;
call myreplace();
drop procedure myreplace;
```

Comment: What is the point to create a SP that only updates a single table? How is it better than an SQL query?

Comment: @zerkms, the advantage is that one can have as many replace operations as one likes in the lookup table. The example here uses a concrete table name, but it is trivial to pass a tablename and it's corresponding fieldname  as parameters.